unresolved import `mpl_token_metadata`
Error Report
Issue:
I am encountering compilation errors when trying to compile my Rust project. The errors are related to unresolved imports and unknown fields in my code.
Error Messages:
error[E0432]: unresolved import `mpl_token_metadata`
 --> programs/context/src/context.rs:4:5
  |
4 | use mpl_token_metadata::ID as MetadataProgramId;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `mpl_token_metadata`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `mpl_token_metadata`
 --> programs/context/src/lib.rs:8:5
  |
8 | use mpl_token_metadata::instruction as mpl_instruction;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `mpl_token_metadata`

warning: unused import: `self`
 --> programs/context/src/context.rs:2:25
  |
2 | use anchor_spl::token::{self, Token, TokenAccount, Mint};
  |                         ^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

warning: unused import: `Metadata`
 --> programs/context/src/lib.rs:6:28
  |
6 | use anchor_spl::metadata::{Metadata, MetadataAccount};
  |                            ^^^^^^^^

warning: unused import: `Token`
 --> programs/context/src/lib.rs:7:31
  |
7 | use anchor_spl::token::{self, Token, Transfer};
  |                               ^^^^^

error[E0609]: no field `token_metadata_program` on type `&mut ImportCollection<'_>`
  --> programs/context/src/lib.rs:45:26
   |
45 |             ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.key(),
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unknown field
   |
   = note: available fields are: `collection`, `authority`, `metadata`, `system_program`, `marketplace_authority`

error[E0609]: no field `token_metadata_program` on type `&mut ImportCollection<'_>`
  --> programs/context/src/lib.rs:58:30
   |
58 |                 ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unknown field
   |
   = note: available fields are: `collection`, `authority`, `metadata`, `system_program`, `marketplace_authority`

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0432, E0609.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
warning: `context` (lib) generated 3 warnings
error: could not compile `context` (lib) due to 4 previous errors; 3 warnings emitted 

Code Context:
Here are the relevant parts of my code:
Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "context"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "context"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []
idl-build = ["anchor-lang/idl-build", "anchor-spl/idl-build"]
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
default = []

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.29.0"
anchor-spl = { version = "0.29.0", features = ["metadata"] }

context.rs:
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token::{self, Token, TokenAccount, Mint};
use crate::state::*;
use mpl_token_metadata::ID as MetadataProgramId; 

lib.rs:
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::metadata::{Metadata, MetadataAccount};
use anchor_spl::token::{self, Token, Transfer};
use mpl_token_metadata::instruction as mpl_instruction;  


Expected Behavior:
The project should compile without any unresolved import errors or unknown field errors.

If you want to use mpl_token_metadata, be sure to include it under your dependencies:
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.29.0"
anchor-spl = { version = "0.29.0", features = ["metadata"] }
mpl-token-metadata = "5"

